# Partial sum of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

If I have

```
year       veg  number
2017 aubergine       3
2017    tomato      13
2017  eggplant       4
2018 aubergine       1
2018    tomato      17
2018  eggplant       3
```

how can I sum the data for `aubergine` and `eggplant` for each year to get

```
year       veg  number
2017 aubergine       7
2017    tomato      13
2018 aubergine       4
2018    tomato      17
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to `replace` `"eggplant"` to `"aubergine"`, then `group_by` `year` and `veg` and take `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(veg = replace(veg, veg == "eggplant", "aubergine")) %>%
  group_by(year, veg) %>%
  summarise(number = sum(number))

#   year veg       number
#  <int> <fct>      <int>
#1  2017 aubergine      7
#2  2017 tomato        13
#3  2018 aubergine      4
#4  2018 tomato        17
```

In base R, that can be done with `transform` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(number~year + veg, 
    transform(df, veg = replace(veg, veg == "eggplant", "aubergine")), sum)
```

Comment: For my case the approach with `transform` and `aggregate` seems the most appropriate for my humble needs.  The solution with `dplyr` is interesting, although I think it is unfortunate the documentation for `mutate` here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html just uses concepts like`tibble` without providing a link.

Answer (score 4):

You could overwrite `eggplant` with `aubergine` and then `aggregate` `number` by `veg` and `year`.

```
x  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="year       veg  number
2017 aubergine       3
2017    tomato      13
2017  eggplant       4
2018 aubergine       1
2018    tomato      17
2018  eggplant       3")

x$vegb  <- x$veg
x$vegb[x$vegb == "eggplant"]  <- "aubergine"

aggregate(number ~ vegb + year, data=x, FUN=sum)
#       vegb year number
#1 aubergine 2017      7
#2    tomato 2017     13
#3 aubergine 2018      4
#4    tomato 2018     17
```

Comment: Creating a new column is a nice idea and one I'll try to remember, although using `transform` as in the second below example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57772285/1409644 seems to me to be a bit more elegant in this case.